# Phonegap Build Android: ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am building the app for android.
But then I see this:

```
[ReferenceError: a is not defined]
exec: ant clean -f "/Users/chaitanya/BPEase/platforms/android/build.xml"
[ 'ant clean -f "/Users/chaitanya/BPEase/platforms/android/build.xml"',
  { [Error: Command failed: 
  BUILD FAILED
  /Users/chaitanya/BPEase/platforms/android/build.xml:90: Cannot find /Applications/eclipse/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml imported from /Users/chaitanya/BPEase/platforms/android/build.xml

  Total time: 0 seconds
  ] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null },
  'Buildfile: /Users/chaitanya/BPEase/platforms/android/build.xml\n',
  '\nBUILD FAILED\n/Users/chaitanya/BPEase/platforms/android/build.xml:90: Cannot find /Applications/eclipse/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml imported from /Users/chaitanya/BPEase/platforms/android/build.xml\n\nTotal time: 0 seconds\n' ]
Error executing "ant clean -f "/Users/chaitanya/BPEase/platforms/android/build.xml"": 
BUILD FAILED
/Users/chaitanya/BPEase/platforms/android/build.xml:90: Cannot find /Applications/eclipse/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml imported from /Users/chaitanya/BPEase/platforms/android/build.xml
```

I have tried to reinstall cordova. Does not give me a positive feedback. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  It would seem that there is a reference to the path to your adt bundle stored in the: `/platforms/android/local.properties` and the `/platforms/android/Cordovalib/local.properties` files.  My issue was that, since these files were checked into source control, they were giving me a path that was configured for another environment.  Modifying them to point to the correct path for my local machine did the trick for me.

Here's a link to a site that helped me figure it out: http://thelogbox.com/cannot-find-buildxml/

Answer (score 0):

you have different version of phonegap installed (maybe 3.4 and application wrote on 3.3). you can change .cordova > config.json file and set the same version of phonegap (3.3)